# Настройка сессий на tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat

Всем привет. Имеется приложение на tomcat 8. Каждый запрос приходящий на это приложение порождает новую сессию. Причём эти сессии висят и не закрываются. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли настроить томкат таким образом, чтобы все запросы приходящие в приложение работали через одну сессию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]